# Ghost.py webscraping list all elements in page

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, ghost.py

I'm trying to fill a form on a webpage with Ghost.py. At the moment i'm struggling with adressing the right form fields, css selectors giving me headaches. So i decided to let Ghost.py do the work and give me a list with form fields and identifiers. So far i have tried:

```
import ghost

g = ghost.Ghost()
with g.start(display=True) as session:
    page, extra_resources = session.open("http://www.surfbirds.com/identifier/what-british-bird.htm")
    if page.http_status == 200 and \
        'Head characters' in page.content:
        print("got it!")
        ressources = 
        session.evaluate('document.getElementByName("geog");')
        print("ressources: {}".format(ressources))
```

This throws an error:

```
Ghost<f836191b-16e6-4a0d-b2c5-96d657556b46>: undefined(0): TypeError: 
'undefined' is not a function
ressources: (None, [])
```

I have no idea what causes this, could someone please point me the direction where i should look?

Comment: Thank-you Herbert, this eliminates the error message but gives back not only the elements inside "geog", but every form inside this page. Nevertheless the error being excluded, I will mark this question as closed. And look for a good tutorial on jquery syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tag on that page named `<geog>`. You probably would like to query for the form element with the name `geog`:

```
document.querySelector('form[name=geog]')
```